# Gradle multi-module project build problem

Tags: gradle, build, multi-module

I have a multi-module project with following structure

[image]

When I try to build **signal-site** project I get this Exception

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
```

settings.gradle.kts (trade) - top level

```
rootProject.name = "trade"
include("trade-common")
include("signal-site")
```

build.gradle.kts (trade) - top level

```
group = "com.oleinikdi"
version = "1.0"

subprojects {
    version = "1.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

settings.gradle.kts (trade-common)

```
rootProject.name = "trade-common"
```

build.gradle.kts (trade-common)

```
subprojects {
    version = "1.0"
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
}

group = "com.oleinikdi"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

settings.gradle.kts (signal-site)

```
rootProject.name = "signal-site"
include("trade-common")
```

build.gradle.kts (signal-site)

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

subprojects {
    version = "1.0"
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    war
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.70"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.70"
}

group = "com.oleinik"
version = "1.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":trade-common"))

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
//    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multi project build, there must be only *one* `settings.gradle` file at the root of the project.

So your issue is caused by having multiple `settings.gradle` defined in your hierarchy, which means when running something in `signal-site`, Gradle is configured to look for `trade-common` as a subfolder of `signal-site`.

Simply remove the `trade-common` and `signal-site` `settings.gradle` files, leaving only the one at the root.

See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file) to get a deeper understanding of Gradle `settings.gradle` files and how they work in multi project setups.